# Is there a log on windows server that shows when a user account was created and which user created it?

Tags: windows-server-2003, users

I'm trying to track down when a user on our system was created, is there any way to tell this in Windows Server 2003?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The create-date is stored in Active Directory, but not the creating entity. The attribute is the whenCreated attribute, which is visible on the 'Object' tab in AD U&C.